# how to use this in combination with div element classname

Tags: jquery, jsp

how use `this` in combination with classname in div tag,

```
 $(this).$('.reason_1').show();
```

Comment: is this the correct way of doing

Comment: why u need to do it? because $(this) is enough to get the element.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i have a table with 10 rows in all those 10 rows i need to display 'reason_1' div contents,when that particular row checkbox is checked

Comment: then you should add this to your post.

Comment: Add more code please it is hard to guess the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to check whether current element has the class `reason_1` then try:

```
If($(this).hasClass('reason_1')){
   $(this).show();
}
```

If you need to change the html then:

```
$(this).html($('.reason_1').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need `hasClass`

```
If($(this).hasClass('.reason_1')){
   $(this).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are trying to find a child of the `this` DOM-object or whether you want to test if `this` actually has class reason_1.

The first can be achieved by

```
$('.reason_1',this).show()
```

or

```
$(this).find('.reason_1').show()
```

For the second case you could write

```
$(this).filter('.reason_1').show()
```

After having seen your additional remark

> i have a table with 10 rows in all those 10 rows i need to display 'reason_1' div contents,when that particular row checkbox is checked

I guess you will have to first move up to the next `tr` from the `this` checkbox using `parents()` and then look for your `.reason_1` divs from there. Something like

```
$(this).parents('tr:eq(0)').find('.reason_1').show()
```

might do the trick.